# Calculating the divergence of electric field in standard coordinates

Tags: divergence-operator, electromagnetism

Given an electric field $$ \vec{E(r)} = (c/r^2 ) \hat {r} $$
I  want to show that $ \nabla \cdot  \vec{E} = 0$ for $ r \ne 0 $ and do the calculation in standard coordinates. For simplicity I'll assume 2 dimensional problem namely $ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $

I have $ \vec{E(r)} = (c/r^2 ) \hat {r} =  cx/r^3 \hat{x} + cy/r^3 \hat{y} = cx (x^2 + y^2)^{-1.5} \hat  x +  cy(x^2 + y^2)^{-1.5} \hat y  $

But now the calculation of

$ \nabla \cdot  \vec{E}  \ne 0 $

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse square law comes about because in three dimensions the surface of a sphere grows as the square of the radius.  If you do the same calculation in three dimensions it will work out.  In two dimensions the field has to fall off as $\frac 1r$ to have zero divergence.

Comment: $ \vec{E(r)} =   cx (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5} \hat  x +  cy(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5} \hat y +  cz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5} \hat z $                                   I might be doing calculation mistake but I still don't get zero. Any idea ?

Comment: I can't see what is wrong without seeing your computation.  I am sure you are not taking the divergence properly.

Comment: $ c (  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5}  - 3x^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-2.5} + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5} -  3y^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-2.5}  + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1.5}  - 3z^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-2.5}  ) $

Comment: Actually it works! Thanks!